# Json encode data formatting

Tags: json

Below part is my json encode data,

```
 [
   {
      project_name: "Faithview 1 Residence",
      BookedUnit: "25",
      GDV: "9,143,860.00"
   }, 
   {
      project_name: "Faithview 2 Residence",
      BookedUnit:   "24", GDV: "8,795,380.00"
   },
   {
      project_name: "Faithview 3 Residence",
      BookedUnit: "24",
      GDV: "8,795,380.00"
   }
 ]
```

I would like to change the json data become like this as shown below:-

```
 [
   {
     project_name: "Faithview 1 Residence",
     Unit: 25
   },
   { 
     project_name: "Faithview 2 Residence",
     Unit: 24
   },
   {
     project_name: "Faithview 3 Residence",
     Unit: 24
   }
 ]
```

There is 3 condition in the new json data which is :-
1) Delete the GDV
2) The key of BookedUnit change to Unit.
3) The format value of "Unit" now become Int.

Any suggestion and solution is appreciated.

Comment: What programming language and platform do you use?

Comment: @CannedMoose ,I am using Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this solution.This is work for you

```js
var oldJSON = [{project_name: "Faithview 1 Residence", BookedUnit: "25", GDV: "9,143,860.00"} , {project_name: "Faithview 2 Residence", BookedUnit: "24", GDV: "8,795,380.00"} , {project_name: "Faithview 3 Residence", BookedUnit: "24", GDV: "8,795,380.00"}];

var newJSON = [];

for(key in oldJSON){
  newJSON[key] = {project_name : oldJSON[key].project_name, Unit : parseInt(oldJSON[key].BookedUnit)};
}

console.log(newJSON);
```

Comment: You can accept my answer by click on the check sign